# pmount not working on Debian wheezy

Tags: debian, permissions

"Not working" might be slightly inaccurate, since it still seems to `mount` and `umount` things properly, but it's inaccessible to users other than the `root` user, which defeats the purpose entirely.

It's still installed on the system, and works fine from the `root` account, but my regular user accounts don't have sufficient privileges to use it. I'm not aware of having changed any permissions relating to mounting, and `remove --purge pmount`ing followed by a re-install does nothing (both with `apt-get` and with `aptitude`.

Any idea what I kicked over by accident?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your users are not in the correct group (plugdev), from [`man pmount`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pmount&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en):

> Important  note  for  Debian:  The  permission  to  execute  pmount 
>   is restricted to members of the system group plugdev. Please add all
>   desk- top users who shall be able to use pmount to this group by
>   executing
>
> ```
>           adduser user plugdev
>
>   (as root).
> ```

Don't forget to either logout after you added the user to the group or use `sg plugdev` to switch to the new group.

Answer (score 2):

You do **not** want to allow arbitrary users to manage pluggable devices. Arbitrary users includes the `nobody` user and the `www-data` user. Do you want a web script to mount/unmount your devices?

Instead, for "pluggable" devices, give the permission via:

```
adduser username plugdev
```

and then re-login as that user to see the changes become effective.